# Си, бинарное дерево

Tags: c, функции, графы, дерево, бинарное-дерево

Сама задача:

В заданном непустом бинарном дереве подсчитать число вершин на n-м уровне, считая корень вершиной 0-го уровня.

Но т.к. только начал разбираться в деревьях решил сначала написать несколько подпрограмм и просто потестить их при работе с деревом.

Сначала пробовал добавлять элементы просто из массива, но вообще нужно из файла.
В обоих случаях в консоли почему то СМАЙЛИКИ
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

первый раз такое вижу, поэтому прошу помочь найти ошибку в коде.

Код:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <locale.h>
//дерево
    typedef struct tagTREE
{
    int inf;
    struct tagTREE* left;
    struct tagTREE* right;
}TREE;
//очередь
typedef struct tagQUEUE
{
    TREE *tr;
    struct tagQUEUE *next;
}QUEUE;
QUEUE *q;
//функция уничтожения очереди
void DestroyQueue()
{
    QUEUE *prev;
    if (q != NULL)
    {
        prev = q;
        while (q->next != NULL)
        {
            q = q->next;
            free(prev);
        prev = q;
        }
        free(prev);
    }
}
//функция добавления элемента в очередь
void Put(TREE *a)
{
    QUEUE *n, *prev;
    prev = q;
    n = malloc(sizeof(QUEUE));
    n->tr = a;
    n->next = NULL;
    if (q != NULL)
    {
        while (prev->next != NULL)
            prev = prev->next;
        prev->next = n;
    }
    else
        q = n;
}
//функция удаления элемента из очереди
TREE* Get()
{
    QUEUE *prev;
    TREE *a;
    if (q != NULL)
    {
        prev = q;
        a = q->tr;
        if (q->next != NULL)
            q = q->next;
        else
            q = NULL;
        free(prev);
        return a;
    }
    else
    return 0;
}
//функция проверки на пустоту очереди
int Empty(QUEUE *q)
{
if (q == NULL) return 1;
else return NULL;
}
//-----------------------------------------------
//функция добавления элемента в дерево
TREE* Add(TREE *root, int x)
{
    if (root == NULL)
    {
    root = malloc(sizeof(TREE));
    root->inf = x;
    root->left = root->right = NULL;
}
else
{
    if (x <= root->inf)
        root->left = Add(root->left, x);
    else
        root->right = Add(root->right, x);
}
return root;
}
//функция удаления элемента из дерева
TREE* Del(TREE *root, int x)
{
TREE *t;
if (root == NULL) return 0;
if (x == root->inf)
{
    if (root->left == NULL)
    {
        t = root->right;
        free(root);
        return t;
    }
    t = root->left;
    while (t->right) t = t->right;
    t->right = root->right;
    return root->left;
}
if (x <= root->inf)
    root->left = Del(root->left, x);
else
    root->right = Del(root->right, x);
return root;
}
//функция вывода дерева на экран
//обходя дерево в ширину
void ShowTree(TREE *root)
{
q = NULL;
TREE *t;
Put(root); 
while (!Empty(q))
{
    t = Get();
    if (t->left != NULL)
        Put(t->left);
    if (t->right != NULL)
        Put(t->right);
    printf("%d ", t->inf);
}
puts("");
}
//функция удаления всего дерева
TREE* DestroyTree(TREE *root)
{
if (root)
{
    if (root->left != NULL)
        root->left = DestroyTree(root->left);
    if (root->right != NULL)
        root->right = DestroyTree(root->right);
    free(root);
}
return NULL;
}
void main(void)
{
setlocale(LC_CTYPE,"Russian");
TREE *mytree = NULL; //указатель на дерево
FILE *file;
int k;
fopen_s(&file, "hello.txt", "r");
if (file == NULL)
    printf("Ошибка при открытии файла");
else {
    printf("Дерево:");
    while (fscanf_s(file, "%d", &k) != EOF)
    {
        mytree = Add(mytree, k);
    }
}
// было так, но вообще нужно читать элементы из файла
//  int mas[10] = { 5, 34, 8, 10, 15, 1, 0, 21, -5, 100 }; 
//  for (i = 0; i<10; i++)
//  mytree = Add(mytree, mas[i]);
//  printf("Дерево:");
//  ShowTree(mytree);

system("cls"); //очищаем экран
ShowTree(mytree);      //выводим дерево
//удаляем элементы
mytree = Del(mytree, k); // критическая ошибка
//  mytree = Del(mytree, 1); пытался удалять элементы из массива 
//  mytree = Del(mytree, -5);
printf("Дерево после удаления элементов:");
ShowTree(mytree);    //выводим дерево
_getch();
}
```

Comment: Ну так а что это за вызовы `puts` и что вы от них вообще ожидаете? Явная ошибка.

Comment: @AnT Да, сейчас пофиксил все предупреждения, остались только эти с puts. Тупанул, сейчас изменю.

Comment: У вас в исходном варианте было правильно - `Put`. А сейчас вы зачем-то "пофиксили" это на какие-то бессмысленные вызовы `puts` и `printf`. Очевидно, код не ваш. Перестаньте менять код - вы совершенно не понимаете, что делаете, т.е. делаете только хуже. Верните все назад, как было в начале.

Comment: @AnT ахахахах, сейчас понял насколько жестко запутался. Сорян за такой глупый вопрос, тему можно закрывать (а лучше удалять :D).

Comment: @летовповерже вместо того, чтобы удалять и закрывать, лучше напишите ответ